# Add a comma before every element but the first one

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

There is a loop:

```php
<?php if ( have_rows( 'fifth-section' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'fifth-section' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'display' ) == 1 ) { ?>
      "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "offers": [
        <?php if( have_rows('plans') ): ?>
        <?php 
          $loop_counter = 0;
          while( have_rows('plans') ): the_row(); 
          if($loop_counter%4 == 0){
            if($loop_counter > 0){ 
            ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php }
          $subtitle = get_sub_field('subtitle');
        ?>                          
        {
          "@type": "Offer",
          "name": "<?php echo $subtitle; ?>",
          "url": "<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"
        },
        <?php 
          $loop_counter++;
          endwhile;
        ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php } else { } ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      ]
    }
  }
```

Which outputs the chunk for the schema markup

```html
"offers": {
      "@type": "AggregateOffer",
      "offers": [                                                       
        {
          "@type": "Offer",
          "name": "title",
          "url": "example.com/assets/1"
        },

        {
          "@type": "Offer",
          "name": "title 2",
          "url": "example.com/assets/2"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the last Offer element after the closing parenthesis } should not have a comma. Elements can be from 1 to 4. Actually a question how to register a comma all the elements except the last one (and, of course, do not add, if the item is 1)?

Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: why you don't use json_encode?

Comment: You can rephrase your problem to: "Add a comma before every element but the first one". This is an easier task, because you can switch a temporary variable on the first iteration. But you need to move a few lines of your code:)

Comment: @splash58 I'm just learning and don't know how to apply json_encode here (

Comment: @jh1711 Oh Yes, it's more correct

Comment: _“don't know how to apply json_encode here”_ - by building up the corresponding data structure first. Which is what you should always prefer over assembling JSON “manually”, whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to add a comma before each element except the first one.

Try adding:

```php
<?php if ($loop_counter > 0) echo ',' ?>
```

Something like that:

```php
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'fifth-section' ) ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_rows( 'fifth-section' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'display' ) == 1 ) { ?>
            "offers": {
                "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                "offers": [
                <?php if( have_rows('tariffs') ): ?>
                <?php 
                    $loop_counter = 0;
                    while( have_rows('tariffs') ): the_row(); 
                    if($loop_counter%4 == 0){
                        if($loop_counter > 0){ 
                        ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php }
                    $tariffs_subtitle = get_sub_field('subtitle');
                    $tariffs_cost = get_sub_field('cost'); 
                ?>                          
                <?php if ($loop_counter > 0) echo ',' ?>
                {
                    "@type": "Offer",
                    "name": "<?php echo $tariffs_subtitle; ?>",
                    "url": "<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>#price",
                    "price": "<?php echo $tariffs_cost; ?>",
                    "priceCurrency": "RUB"
                }
                <?php 
                    $loop_counter++;
                    endwhile;
                ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } else { } ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            ]
        }
    }
```